# Custom condition for OpenLayers 3 draw interaction

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

When I give a custom (as in not one of OL's predefined ones) `condition` function to an `ol.interaction.Draw`, the `condition` is only called with `'pointerdown'` events.

Is this an OpenLayers bug? Can you suggest a fix or a workaround?

**Background:**
I am trying to build a point feature selector, which selects features when they are clicked (and a polygon is not being drawn), or by a drawn polygon.

To this end I am trying to juggle an `ol.interaction.Select` and an `ol.interaction.Draw`, which both respond to `'click'` events, but only according to (mutually exclusive) conditions defined by me.

If I log all events received by either interaction's `condition`, I see that the `Select` interaction receives many (such as `'pointerdown'`, -`up'`, -`move'`, `'click'` and `'singleclick'`), while the `Draw` interaction only receives `'pointerdown'`, making it impossible to handle `'click'`.

[This plunk illustrates](http://plnkr.co/edit/DM9xF5?p=preview) (enable dev tools to see log messages).

Comment: I have posted a [bug report](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/6503) with the issue.